# My discord bot is not responding to my commands

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
      channel = message.channel
      await channel.send('Hello!')


client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

I tried to make a discord bot using discord.py. The bot comes online and everything but does not respond to my messages. Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Are you using discord.py 2?

Comment: There is an indentation error in the `on_message` function - logic is unreachable with that return statement. Maybe that is just a typo when you wrote up the question.

Comment: ^^^ you also need [message content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message_content#discord.Intents.message_content) intent to access the content of the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have an indentation error:

```py
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
      channel = message.channel
      await channel.send('Hello!')
```

The last if-statement is never going to be executed. Instead, move it one indentation back such that:

```py
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
    channel = message.channel
    await channel.send('Hello!')
```